# Datagridview adds up unwanted rows

Tags: c#, datagridview

The last line of this code is supposed to fill in a row with 3 columns in a datagridview every time the variable "temperature" and "umidita" are shown in the relevant text boxes.

These data comes from the serial port and get updated every x seconds.

```
private void SetText(string text)
    {
        string temperatura;
        string umidita;

        if (this.txtOutput.InvokeRequired)
        {
            SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(SetText);
            this.BeginInvoke(d, new object[] { text });
        }

        else
        {

            string f = text;
            char firstChar = f[0];

            if (firstChar == 'T')
            {
                temperatura = f;
                temperatura = f.Replace("T", "");
                textBox1.Text = temperatura;
            }

            else if (firstChar == 'U')
            {
                umidita = f;
                umidita = f.Replace("U", "");
                textBox2.Text = umidita;
            }
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(new string[] { DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss"), textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text });
        }
    }
```

The code is working but I get 3 rows at time filled in with the same data.

[image]

I am not familiar with datagridview and I do not understand why I am getting such behavior. What do I need to change to get one row at time filled in with time, "temperatura" and "umidita"?

Comment: Maybe Rows.Add is executed 3 times? can you put a breakpoint and verify ?

Comment: Yes, it is executed 3 times. But why?

Comment: Is `SetText` called multiple times? It could be the data input.

Comment: Yes. It is called multiple times, basically every time there is a new data available. I do not know I to get right here!

Comment: Most probably you have wired it to some event from serial port and that event is triggered multiple times.

Comment: Also the second part of time might be equal, but its possible that the exact timespan is different.

Comment: Sorry, I meant  to say: Is `SetText` called multiple times with the same value of `text`?

Comment: Thanks for showing me the direction. I have moved the line under a timer event triggered with 10 ms interval under a timer tick event and the problem is solved. A little bit rude but looks like it is now working. On the other hands I cannot change the rest of the code because would affect other features.

Comment: Or you could skip adding a row, if data grid already contained the current time.

Answer (score 0):

////you can check if you already inserted a row in this time

```
int rowsCount = dataGridView1.Rows.Count;
        string cuurentTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
        if (cuurentTime != dataGridView1.Rows[rowsCount - 1].Cells[0].Value.ToString())
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(new string[] { cuurentTime, textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text });
        }
```

Comment: It would never be the same time. Just few millisec difference and the line you suggested does not work. Actually the problem is generated from the micro sending the data on the serial port. It sends one string at time with the recorder value, so the data comes in separate packets. However thanks for the suggestion. Right now the timer delay 10 ms is working fine, in any case records comes with 30 seconds intervals so there is plenty of time to avoid problems with the timer.